# Convert file of ASCII decimals into their symbol then output to a new file?

Tags: c++, file-io, ascii

I have a list of numbers in a text file and I am trying to make a console application in C++ which converts those ASCII decimals into their symbol and then outputs them into a new file. For example, the ASCII decimal 88 into 'X'.

The text file looks as follows:

```
84
104
101
32
99
111
100
101
32
105
115
58
32
53
52
57
57
52
53
```

So far this is what I've got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("Output.txt");

    if (infile.fail()){
        cerr << "Error Opening File" << endl;
        //Terminate
    }


    int number;
    int count = 0;


    while(!infile.eof()){
        infile >> number;
        count++;

    }

    cout << count << " Number(s) Found!" << endl;


    cout << "\nConverting To Ascii!" << endl;

    //Convert To ASCII and Output to new file   



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I've looked online about itoa and sprintf but I don't understand the functions well enough to figure out how to implement it in this way.

Comment: Unrelated: Stop doing this: `while(!infile.eof())`. [Read this to find out why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Did you just try `std::cout << static_cast<unsigned char>(number) << '\n';` ? I.e. stop looking for a needle when all you need is the haystack.

Comment: Do you know enough C++ to be able to figure out what "char c=88; std::cout <<c;"  will do? If you don't try it and see if you can figure out what the rest of your program should be. If you do know what this will do, then what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I have not tried this yet. I'm going to read up on this and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: "Did you just try std::cout << static_cast<unsigned char>(number) << '\n'; ? I.e. stop looking for a needle when all you need is the haystack." Thanks! This works. I'm going to make sure I understand it well.